# replace special characters in a alternate text of image

Tags: str-replace, replace

I am trying to generate alternate text for the images in my blog to make my work easily and i found a mistake in the execution of this script.
If the image name is "image_good_looking.jpg" the output will be "image_good_looking".
Good upto some extent. If the image name is"image good looking.jpg" before upload it changes to "image+good+looking.jpg". I tried filename.replace("+"," "),title.replace("+"," ") But in the output there is no change in title and alternate text of the image.

this script must be placed after  section

var filename = $img.attr('src')
 $img.attr('title', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));

Answer (score 0):

```
$img.attr('title',filename.replace(/\W/," "));
```

This will replace all non-alfanumeric characters with space.
Is this what are you looking for ?

Comment: No man.I am getting complete url instead of name with special char.$img.attr('title', filename.substring((filename.lastIndexOf('/'))+1, filename.lastIndexOf('.')));
$img.attr('title', title.replace("+"," ")); i tried in this way but i lost my image name and i got the total url of the image. i am in gtalk @ sanampuri.somasekhar@gmail.com. i really need your help to make it possible. i will be waiting for your mail.